# How to get 0 as the first term of my fibonacci sequece?

Tags: python, while-loop, fibonacci

I can't figure out how to display 0 as the output of my Fibonacci sequence function when the input is 0. How can I do so using the while loop?

```
def Fibonacci(n):
    i= 0
    present = 1
    previous = 0
    while i <= n:
        nextterm = present + previous

        present = previous
        previous = nextterm
        i += 1
    return nextterm 

I expect the output of Fibonacci(0) to be 0
```

Comment: Your while loop runs one due to the `i <= n` condition is you pass in `0`. so you get `1`

Comment: You can add `0` as an edge-case to get around the issue.

Comment: Can’t you use if inside Fibonacii function before while loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current code can be fixed by returning `present` rather than `nextterm`.

In case you're curious, a common Fibonacci implementation in Python often looks like this. The variable naming in this version seems a bit more intuitive to me.

```
def fib(n):
    cur, nxt = (0, 1)
    while n > 0:
        cur, nxt = (nxt, cur + nxt)
        n -= 1
    return cur
```

Answer (score 0):

It must be returning 1,its gona enter the loop when n=0 and will put 1 in nextterm.